# Deleting from large table taking too long when using filter WHERE Field IN (<empty set>)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a peculiar problem I don't quite understand. There's this large table, let's call it `LT`, with a primary key `ID`. I have a `DELETE` statement to delete duplicates that goes something like this:

```
DELETE FROM LT
WHERE ID IN ( 
    SELECT l.ID FROM ( 
        SELECT Field1, Field2, COUNT(*) as total, MIN(ID) LowestID FROM LT (NOLOCK) WHERE Field1 = @fieldOneParam 
        GROUP BY Field1, Field2
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
    ) a 
    INNER JOIN LT l (NOLOCK) on l.Field1 = a.Field1 And l.Field2 = a.Field2 And l.ID > a.LowestID 
)
```

Not, if there are results in that nested select, the query runs relatively fast. However, when this subquery:

```
SELECT l.ID FROM ( 
    SELECT Field1, Field2, COUNT(*) as total, MIN(ID) LowestID FROM LT (NOLOCK) WHERE Field1 = @fieldOneParam 
    GROUP BY Field1, Field2
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
) a 
INNER JOIN LT l (NOLOCK) on l.Field1 = a.Field1 And l.Field2 = a.Field2 And l.ID > a.LowestID
```

Returns an empty set, the whole statement runs forever. I've checked the estimated execution plan, and it's filled with table spools, nested loops and seeking every single index the table has (which are many). Not for the subquery, but for the deletion itself.

Why does it do that? Shouldn't it just use the clustered index for the `ID` field (which it has)? Shouldn't the query run in a few seconds since the set for the `IN (...)` clause is empty?

Thanks.

Comment: does your query runs forever if you just replace the subquery with in (select 1 from LT where 1 = 0) ?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question, but here is an alternative way to delete duplicates while keeping the lowest `id` per `Field1, Field2` using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (
        partition by t.Field1, t.Field2 
        order by t.Id
      )
  from lt as t
)
--delete 
select * -- preview
from cte
where rn > 1;
```

---

The `NOLOCK` hint in your original query may be causing your problem.

- [Bad Habits: Putting NOLOCK everywhere - Aaron Bertrand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)
- [SQL Server Isolation Levels: A Series - Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/07/t-sql-queries/isolation-levels)

Answer (score 1):

While not a specific answer to performance question, consider a one-level correlated subquery:

```
DELETE FROM LT
WHERE LT.ID > ( 
    SELECT MIN(sub.ID)
    FROM LT sub
    WHERE sub.Field1 = @fieldOneParam 
      AND sub.Field1 = LT.Field1 AND sub.Field2 = LT.Field2
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1     
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed similar behavior before.

If you save the ID's to a temp table you can delete from the main table where the ID's are in the temp table.

So in your code, you could modify it to:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (ID int PRIMARY KEY)

SELECT l.ID 
INTO @temp
FROM ( 
        SELECT Field1, Field2, COUNT(*) as total, MIN(ID) LowestID FROM LT (NOLOCK) WHERE Field1 = @fieldOneParam 
        GROUP BY Field1, Field2
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
    ) a 
    INNER JOIN LT l (NOLOCK) on l.Field1 = a.Field1 And l.Field2 = a.Field2 And l.ID > a.LowestID

DELETE FROM LT
WHERE LT.ID IN (SELECT ID 
                  FROM @temp)
```